# singleton pattern in sitecore MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, singleton, sitecore

My solution has a base layout. Is it possible to create an object of helper classes in this layout, and hence the same object can be used in all views in the page?

Comment: It is not possible. That's not how MVC works in Sitecore. If you want helper methods for razor scripts, create them in the `App_Code` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of... One option would be to instantiate this on each request and then assign that object to the `HttpContext.Items[]` collection. This helper object would live for the duration of a single request, so would be null for subsequent requests unless re-initialised. One gotcha with this is that you would need to make sure this is assigned by the first item rendered for a given page (your base layout should be ok for this).

Within a controller action, you could use something like this to assign to the HttpContext:

```
base.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Items["MyHelper"] = new HelperClass();
```

Then you would retrieve that object using:

```
var helper = base.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Items["MyHelper"] as HelperClass;
if (helper != null) {
    var stuff = helper.GetStuff();
}
```

As a side-note, making shared helper objects like this kind of goes against the grain of MVC development (even of WebForms actually). It would be better, from an architecture perspective, to create a new instance of your helper class in each controller where required - take a look at "controller injection" if you want to learn more about that.